# finding Information about an unknown device on a different network

Tags: ip, network-protocols, subnet

It is very common for some of our inexperienced customers to mess around with the network settings on our devices. They often end up changing IP and subnet mask and then calling the support hotline and complaining about the device being unreachable. Therefore, we are trying to design a software that can detect the network configuration of the device, even if it is on a different network than the host PC. Is there anyway to achieve this, even if the MAC address is also unknown? We will be using teamview to gain access to the customer's PC.

Comment: if you are connected to clients pc, you can see all network settings and compare them to expected settings.

Comment: @ VickiaR : not really. The device would be unreachable because it sits on a different subnet.

Comment: And how do you connect to him? :-)

Comment: you are confusing the PC with the device. With Teamviewer you gain access to the host PC but not to the device.

Comment: I guess there is no way to connect to the device if it is on a different network than the PC, unless there is a router in between to connect both networks to each other.

Comment: No, it is possible to connect to device which is on different subnet (logical subnet, not physical network) directly. You need add route to that device. P.S.: in TCP/IP terminology device and PC is the same.

Comment: Seen as though it are your devices, if you create a script that automatically fills in the network details when the user starts messing around with it? Because once the settings are changed and the device is unreachable I doubt you'll be able to do anything about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to solve the problem by letting all of our units join a multicast group. With multicast, it is possible to etablish a connection between subnets. I defined special UDP Datagrams, which let all units present in a network send their network configuration to the host. This way, one can always keep an eye on them and detect them. I'm also thinking about changing the configuration using multicast. But at least the main problem has been solved. Many thanks to everyone for their input.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you provide a public (i.e. globally routable, not private) IP address on one of the devices interfaces? If so, why can't connect to device itself? However, this path requires spending reasonable time working on security aspects.

If you have a device, connected to PC via an Ethernet cable (which, I think, is the most popular case), you can find out device's MAC address by simply sniffing traffic on relevant interface. If you get more than one MAC address, you can filter your device's address by OUI.
You can get the IP address of a device interface analyzing the same traffic dump.

> I guess there is no way to connect to the device if it is on a different network than the PC

If it were production network, I would think about using proxy arp. You could use it on the device, on the 'inside' interface (the one PC connects to). And I never tried to enable proxy arp on a PC.

It would help a lot to develop some view on your problem, if you provide some more information, i.e. what does the device do, where does it connect, maybe apply a sample configuration.

Comment: it's a building automation module that we sell to companies. The companies then send technicians to install the modules in buildings. Our experience has shown that some technicians are also not very experienced when it comes to networking, so they end up messing around with the network configurations making the device unreachable. So far we have been able to fix the issues by connecting the devices directly to the host pc using a serial cable and changing the network configurations. However, our experience has also shown that some technicians tend to forget to bring the serial cable ->>

Comment: ->> and it's a special serial cable, which can be only bought directly from our company. Now here's what I've tried so far:
- Nmap, find ipaddress by looking for the mac address of the device, add a route to the  device on the host PC, acces the device and change the settings. However, without knowing any octet of the ip address, it may take a day or 2 of scanning till we find the IP address.

Comment: -Idea: ping 255.255.255.255 and populate the arp cache with IP addresses and their corresponding mac addresses and find the device. But this seen to only work on local networks.

P.S.: the network configurations are stored in an .ini file. So the only way to change the settings is by editing this file.

Answer (score 1):

> However, without knowing any octet of the ip address, it may take a day or 2 of scanning till we find the IP address

Assuming we need to scan whole IPv4 address space using now-ubiqutuous 1gig ethernet interfaace (linerate 1.5 Mpps), we need approx. 2**32/1500000=2863 seconds to send all the probes. Adding some time for analysis and other logic we still need hours, not days. Futhermore, we can scan only usual 10/8,172.16/12,192.168/16 ranges. We'll need only 11 seconds to send all the probes to RFC1918 addresses at 1gig linerate.

My other point is, you should really think about implementing some kind of reset button[/action/menu item], which saves current configuration and loads a predefined safe configuration, with known IP address.

Also, do you have some other communication channel on the device, like GSM/CDMA modem? If so, you theoretically could implement access to the device this way.

Comment: your post is very informative and I wish some technicians would read it. The problem is, most of the time the clients assign IP addresses outside the usual ranges. Just to give you an idea of who we are dealing with: a client once complained about our module having messed up his internet connection, his configuration: a 255.255.255.254 subnet: 1 IP address for the module, 1 IP address for global broadcast i.e. 255.255.255.255 and none left for the host PC! 
...

Comment: We are already considering implementing a reset button, however it is not as easy as it sounds, since a certain control software will have to reuploaded to the device and in some circumstances this may take a long time depending on the size and complexity of the software.
The modules only offer Ethernet and serial interfaces for the interaction with the outside world. The rest are bus interface (CAN, I2C ...)

Answer (score 0):

Well, good luck then.

> I'm also thinking about changing the configuration using multicast.

Please make sure to use some sort of authentication and message signing.